# Disabling windows key functions while the program is in focus (c++)

Tags: c++, windows, hook, juce

The idea of disabling the windows key I was able to find online, right now Im using a low level keyboard hook, but it disables the use of the key for the lifetime of the app. Is there a solution to this problem where I can just do it while the program is in focus?

Im using a low level hook at the moment so ideally want to expand on this idea.

Comment: React to loose focus message and enable key again? Or better make sure you first get the key state (enabled/disabled) and set it back to that.

Comment: Linux, MacOS, Windows, sth-cross platform? Any more context on what you're using?